# How to prove that $\cos x< \cos (\sin x)$ using the mean value theorem?

Tags: calculus, rolles-theorem

> Using the mean value theorem, prove that, for $0<x<\pi/2$, $\cos x<\cos(\sin x)$.

I was trying to use the mean value theorem but I got lost. I am a newbie to this please explain this as you're explaining it to your worst student!

Comment: Use $x>\sin x$.

Comment: as Dark Mathorp pointed that you might need to show that $x>\sin(x)$ so I show you how to show that $x>\sin(x)$. Note that $x-\sin(x)$ is a convex function for $x=(0,\pi /2)$ and its minimum value is obtained when $x=0$. Hence $x>\sin(x)$ for your desired values of $x$.

Comment: Okay I understood your answer but is the proof doable using mean value theorem?

Comment: I took f(x) = cos x - cos(sin x) and I'm trying to prove that this function is strictly decreasing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that

- $x>\sin x$
- $\cos x$ is a strictly decreasing function on the interval

Answer (score 1):

You can show that $\cos(x)$ is decreasing on that and then use the fact that $x > \sin(x)$ (you may have to show this as well, but that is not a challenge).